# Page layout shift right slightly on mobile devices

Tags: android, ios, css, mobile, layout

I am a beginner in web design and I complied my site for assignment purpose, purely using codes and no visual design software.

I completed the page & submitted for browser compatibility. It looks mostly fine, but only show a shift of the bottom columns to right slightly on mobile devices I tested that again on my android tablet and iPhone and got the same result.

I tried-
Reset the CSS.

Clear less position: absolute
Changed margin to padding setting
but it is still the same.

Can anyone help me to look at the codes and tell me how to solve this?

The CSS:
www.relicsnselves.comoj.com/style.css (sorry try to post the CSS here too but failed...)

The html: (Sorry tried to embed the code here, but failed.) Please see 
http://jsfiddle.net/qNjfF/ `

```
    <div id="col1">
        <a href=# target="_blank"><h3>New paper - "Paper Title"</h3>
        <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</h4> </a></div>

        <div id="col2">
            <a href="" target="_blank"><h3>Latest tour - "State Fetishes"</h3> 
            <img src="images/gallery/tour/IB18-01.jpg" alt="" width=auto height=300px></a></div>


        <div id="col3">
            <a href="" target="_blank"><h3> New exhibit - "Governor of Chile"</h3> <img src="images/gallery/exhibit/Ch10-22.jpg" alt="" width=auto height=300px ></a> </div>

        <div id="clear"></div>
            <div id="col4">Curated by
                <img src="" width=100px; height=40px > </img>
                <img src="" width=100px; height=40px> </img></div> 


    </div>`
```

view here

> [relicsnselves.comoj.com/index.html](http://relicsnselves.comoj.com/index.html)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your link is not viewable, you are in a developer/parked site. Can you post to codepen please, that way we can look at it in mobile. Thanks.

Comment: nm cant view it on mobile.

Comment: [https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8346562] and [http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mqwul]

Thanks for your help!